# String indices must be integers in api wrapping in Python

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to wrap the weather api from https://www.visualcrossing.com/ to get humidity and temperature for the exact hour, based on this query:
https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/Poborka%20Wielka%2C%20Poland/2022-09-03/2022-09-03?unitGroup=metric&key=YourKey&contentType=json

The JSON I get back looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/KubaHKM/veg7bfpt/2/

To get humidity and temperature for the exact hour I tried to approach it that way:

```
def generate_response(place, day, hour):

    ctx = {
        "date": day,
        "hour": hour,
        "temperature": 0,
        "humidity": 0
    }

    response = wr.get_weather_report(place, day)

    try:
        for hours in response["days"]:
            for h in hours:
                if h["datetime"] == hour:
                    ctx["finalResponse"].append({
                        "hour": h["datetime"],
                        "temperature": h["temp"],
                        "humidity": h["humidity"]
                    })
                else:
                    pass
    except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
        print(e)
    ctx["msg"] = {
        "type": "error",
        "content": "Cloud connection error"
        }

    print (ctx)
```

where wr.get.weather is a function passing the arguments and parameters to a request and calling the API.

As mentioned in the title, I get: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on line: `if h["datetime"] == hour:`

I know what the error is about but I really don't know how to push the solution closer to what I need, since the debugger shows that hours value is my JSONs value, so the thing that I needed.
I would really much appreciate your help in understanding how to get to the exact data I need.

Comment: do you need to parse the response as json?

Comment: Yes, @TomMcLean

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
> def generate_response(place, day, hour):
```

but you might equivalently have said

```
> def generate_response(place: str, day: str, hour: str):
```

That is, the initial line of the function
could safely

```
        assert isinstance(hour, str)
```

Later you create a dictionary:

```
                   ... {
                        "hour": hour["datetime"],
                        "temperature": hour["temp"],
                        "humidity": hour["humidity"]
                    } ...
```

That's three `hour[foo]` expressions.
But `hour` is a str rather than a dict.
You might try subscripting `hours[foo]`,
but it seems much more likely that you
intended `h[foo]` in those three spots.

---

> I know what the error is about ...

From what you wrote, it isn't clear
to me that you know what it's about.

We can talk about integer subscript `'abc'[1]`,
but not `'abc'['def']`.
You typically would need to be dereferencing a dict
for the string subscript to work.

You mentioned an `if hour['datetime'] == hour`
statement, but the posted code does not
contain that statement.

tl;dr: Looks like a typo / syntax issue.

EDIT

Let's define a dictionary `d`,
containing integer values.
We can dereference it using
any of its keys.

Notice that dereferencing it with
integer subscripts won't work.
Such subscripts will work fine on
other containers, such as a `str`
or a `list`.

```
>>> d = dict(abcd=1, efgh=5, ijkl=9)
>>> d
{'abcd': 1, 'efgh': 5, 'ijkl': 9}
>>> 
>>> list(d.values())
[1, 5, 9]
>>> 
>>> list(d.keys())
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']
>>>
>>> d[1]  # fail!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 1
>>>  
>>> d['abcd']
1
>>> d['efgh']
5
>>>
>>>
>>> 'abcd'[2]
'c'
>>>
>>> list(d.values())[2]
9
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed the typo.
The older version had hour and hour_formatted, but some functions changed, so it's rather 'if h["datetime"] == hour'
The code broke either way, even with hour_formatted as a variable and hour as an iterator, since it breaks on the if statement before the new json creation.

And yes I don't really understand this part:
"You typically would need to be dereferencing a dict for the string subscript to work." If you could repeat it in some easier times, it would be great.